# Javascript - how to split a string based on word count and also wrap each new shorter sentence in quotation marks

Tags: javascript, string

If I have a string such as:

"Routines are well established and everybody knows what they're supposed to be doing."

How can I use javascript to split that string after every four words *and* return it in a comma separated list, with each new shorter string wrapped in its own quotation marks, like so:

"Routines are well established", "and everybody knows what", "they're supposed to be", "doing."

Currently I am using:

```
let string = "Routines are well established and everybody knows what they're supposed to be doing.";

var result = string.split(/((?:\\S+\\s*){4})/g).filter(Boolean).join(',');
```

and this is returning:

`Routines are well established ,and everybody knows what ,they're supposed to be ,doing.`

So I'm just missing the step to get the quotation marks around each chunk of the sentence.

Comment: `'"' + ([...].join('", "')) + '"'`